# Calling a method as a method parameter but not executing?

Tags: c#, .net, methods, delegates, func

Hi I am trying to implement a method that will take a method (any method in the grand scheme of things) as a parameter. I want this parameter method to run when in the method that called it only, If the method that passes into this method has a return value then it should still be able to return its value.

I want to measure the performance of the methods that are passed in.

```
return Performance(GetNextPage(eEvent, false));

public static T Performance<T>(T method)
{
    T toReturn;
    Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    toReturn = method;
    sw.Stop();
    Debug.WriteLine(sw.Elapsed.ToString());
    return toReturn;
}
```

I have tried using `Action` which does work almost how I want to use it

```
public static TimeSpan Measure(Action action)
{
    Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    action();
    sw.Stop();
    return sw.Elapsed;
}

var dur = Measure(() => GetNextPage(eEvent, false));
```

Problem is `action()` returns `void` so I can't use it the way I would like to.

I have looked at `Func` but I don't see how I can get it to run my `Performance` method with the `GetNextPage` method passed in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass `Func<T>` to `Performance`:

```
public static T Performance<T>(Func<T> func)
{
    T toReturn;
    Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    toReturn = func();
    sw.Stop();
    Debug.WriteLine(sw.Elapsed.ToString());
    return toReturn;
}
```

I think you'll also need your separate `Measure` method for methods that don't return values, accepting `Action` as it currently does.

Your call to `Performance` becomes:

```
return Performance(() => GetNextPage(eEvent, false));
```

`eEvent` and `false` become part of the closure, so it's just the return result of `GetNextPage` that is acquired and returned.